# PHP and MySQL query inside an a href

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a little bit of problem to found why isn't my query working.

My problem is that i have to take the TID to create a link to the database entry I am showing.

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `titulo`, `uid`, `tid`,`username` FROM `treinos` ORDER BY tid DESC limit 4";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo ('Titulo: <a href="treino.php?id="' . $row["tid"] . '">' .  $row['titulo'] . "</a> Usuario " . $row['usuario'] );
    echo '</br>';    
}
```

for some reason the `$row['tid']` doesn't work inside the  area, but outside is working perfectly for exampleif a change the `$row['titulo']` to `$row['tid']` the query is going to give me the info.

Comment: what do you mean 'doesn't work'? Does it throw an error?

Comment: No error, just return a blank link like example.com/treino.php?id=

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` anymore: it's being deprecated... switch to either [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO) or [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 5):

You have a rogue `"` in your `href`. Remove the `"` after `id=`.

```
echo ('Titulo: <a href="treino.php?id=' . $row["tid"] . '">' .  $row['titulo'] . "</a> Usuario " . $row['usuario'] );
```

Answer (score 3):

The error lies in the `id="`. You close the `href` before you print the id. So change it to:

`echo ('Titulo: <a href="treino.php?id=' . $row["tid"] . '">' .  $row['titulo'] . "</a> Usuario " . $row['usuario'] );`